# fopen for each function or storing file in list or array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, fopen, fgets

Lets say I am writing a program with 3-5 functions, all of which handle the same input file consisting of 25-50 lines of strings made up of 100 characters each. I want to use the strings from this file for various string operations like removing vowels and consonants, replacing characters, or just printing out the whole file.

Is it preferred to store these lines in for example an array or linked list? Or should I just use fopen and fgets for each function? Storage is only during runtime.

And in general, what is the best way to handle input files when dealing with the same file in multiple functions?

Comment: It depends on whether you want to store permanently or till the program dies. Your question isn't clear enough

Comment: Either declare a **global** stream `FILE *fp` (not recommended) or declare the stream in `main()` and pass the stream as an argument to your functions to provide access to the file. E.g.: `function (FILE *f, ...)`.

Answer (score 3):

Provided there's no *other* programs or people modifying the file outside of your own program, it's more efficient to load all the data into memory and use/modify it there, writing it back to the file whenever you want it updated.

That *may* be just before exiting the program, or it may be after every change or it may be when the user hits `File/Save`.

It's not efficient having to open, read, write and close a file multiple times during a program run unless you need the actual information *in* the file during the run.